# Check OrderedDict based on index in csv?

Tags: python, indexing, collections, items, ordereddictionary

I'm trying to do different checks based on the index number of a dictionary. So, if index == 0, do something, otherwise if index>0, do something else.

I was trying to use `OrderedDict` and index it based on `items()`. But if I say, `od.items()[0]`, it just gives me the name of the first element. Not the ability to write an `if` conditional based on whether the first element has already been checked.

Also I would prefer not to check my conditional based on the actual value in the `example.csv` file, since it will change daily.

Here is my code and example data in the csv file.

`Example.csv`

```
Key_abc, Value894
Key_xyz, Value256
Key_hju, Value_567
```

Code:

```
with open('example.csv','rb') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    od = collections.OrderedDict(r)
    for row in od:
        if od.items() == 0:
            print 'do some checks and run code'
            print row, od[row]
        elif od.items() > 0:
            print 'go through code without checks'
            print row, od[row]
```

Comment: Index of what from the csv?

Comment: What is the "index number of a dictionary"? I think you want `enumerate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could do something like this. (The example below is written in **python3** syntax).

```
#ExampleCode
with open('example.csv') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    od = collections.OrderedDict(r)
    for index, row in zip(collections.count(), od):
        if index == 0:
            print('do some checks and run code')
            print(row, od[row])
        elif index > 0:
            print('go through code without checks')
            print(row, od[row])
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here: `zip(collections.count(), od)`? I think you want `enumerate(od)`

Comment: Thanks cyber-cap and juanpa.arrivillaga. Putting the index in front of row and enumerate(od) gives me exactly what I wanted. I modified the initial answer with the correction.